# Ionic Google Map API loads occasionally

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

Trying to test an app using the google API with Ionic and for some reason sometimes it will display google maps and sometimes it won't at random. We do not get any error's thrown or any issues, it simply just does not load the google API's map.

Controller:

```
.controller('Extra', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                                  mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };


});
```

HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Extra">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    </script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&amp;sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue. Got the same. Sometimes the map is shown, sometimes not...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your requirement.but i have created a small example for you.By using below code,you can display google map.If you need any additional functionality.please let me know?

**Controller**

```
.controller('searchCtrl', function($scope) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493, -89.381388);
    var mapOptions = {
        streetViewControl: true,
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    $scope.map = map;
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <ion-view view-title="Extra">
     <ion-content>
      <div id="map" style="height:500px;" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>                
     </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    </script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
          The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
        -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
          The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
          Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
          have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
        -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```