# Google Maps in Cordova and ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

Just started developing hybrid apps with the ionic framework, and ran into a little problem.

I am trying to embed a Google map, but can't wrap my head around a lille issue.

1. First, I downloaded and implemented the "Angular Google Maps" from
   http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/
2. Then I created a API key through the Google developer console.
3. Added my applications id, from the config.xml, to the allowed url's
4. Added the key as part of the config section:

   ```
   uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
     key: 'added the key here',
     v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
     libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
   });
   ```
5. Added uiGmapgoogle-maps as a module
6. Placed `<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>` where I wanted the map to be.

....and now the problem:
When I fire up the app in the Ripple emulator, the maps shows just fine, for a second, and then tells me that the page was unable to display a Google Maps element, and gives me an "InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError", but it is an periodic error, because somethimes it actually works, without throwing an error, but then I try it on a live device, and the screen is just blank.

It is pretty safe to say, that I forgot something, or doing something wrong, but thank you very much in advance.

[EDIT]Well, if I remove all the restrictions for the Google Maps API, it works in the Ripple emulator, so I can change the question to: What url am I supposed to specify as allowed, when it is a cordova app?
And what causes the empty map when executed on a real device?[/EDIT]

Comment: Could be a duplication somewhere.Check your index.html for google maps references. If so, look for an API key somewhere there.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236323/ionic-google-map-api-loads-occasionally/32241816#32241816

Comment: Sorry, but I already tried the above method, and it gives me the excact same error, where the app is not authorized to use that key, and an empty map on a live device.